# Solution for a particular inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-inequalities

I'm following up on this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396004/simple-example-of-hammerstein-integral-equation)  on MathOverflow. By taking some particular functions, $a(.),\,b(.)$ and $K(.,.)$.

This problem is equivalent to the following inequality:

$$4\left \| r \right \|_{\infty}\big(t^\frac{5}{6}-t^\frac{1}{3}ln(1+t^\frac{1}{2})\big)\leq r(t),\,t\in[0,1].\:(I)$$

I'm looking for a function $r \in \mathcal{C}\big(I,(0, \infty)\big)$ which verifies $(I)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Define
$$
f(t) = 4 \, (t^{5/6} - t^{1/3} \ln(1 + t^{1/2})).$$
Then, $f$ is continuous and $f(1) = 4 (1 - \ln(2)) \approx 1.227$.
Hence, your inequality implies
$$ 1.1 \, \|r\|_\infty \le r(t)$$
for all $t$ in the neighborhood of $1$,
but this is not possible.